# Calculate percentiles? (Or more generally, evaluate function implicitly defined by 2 vectors x and y at many values z)

Tags: matlab, statistics, percentile

Let's say you have some vector `z` and you compute `[f, x] = ecdf(z);`, hence your empirical CDF can be plotted with `stairs(x, f)`.

Is there a simple way to compute what all the percentile scores are for `z`?

I could do something like:

- Loop through `z`, that is for each entry `z(i)` of `z`

  - Binary search through sorted vector `x` to find where `z(i)` is. (find index `j` such that x(j) = z(i))
  - Find the corresponding value `f(j)`

It feels like there should be a simpler, already implemented way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `f` be a **monotone function** defined at values `x`, for which you want to compute the inverse function at values `p`. In your case `f` is monotone because it is a CDF; and the values `p` define the desired quantiles. Then you can simply use [`interp1`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to interpolate `x`, considered as a function of `f`, at values `p`:

```
z = randn(1,1e5); % example data: normalized Gaussian distribution
[f, x] = ecdf(z); % compute empirical CDF
p = [0.5 0.9 0.95]; % desired values for quantiles
result = interp1(f, x, p);
```

In an example run of the above code, this produces

```
result =
   0.001706069265714   1.285514249607186   1.647546848952448
```

---

For the specific case of **computing quantiles** `p` from data `z`, you can directly use [`quantile`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html) and thus avoid computing the empirical CDF:

```
result = quantile(z, p)
```

The results may be slightly different depending on how the empirical CDF has been computed in the first method:

```
>> quantile(z, p)
ans =
   0.001706803588857   1.285515826972878   1.647582486507752
```

---

For comparison, the theoretical values for the above example (Gaussian distribution) are

```
>> norminv(p)
ans =
                   0   1.281551565544601   1.644853626951472
```